# Adding rows to large excel dataset

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel worksheet that I am working in, it has approximately 28k rows,

I am importing data from a secondary excel sheet, however, the formatting is different.

The data is, for example, daily data from 1951-2011, and I need to insert a row at the end of every year for calculations I am doing.

I have looked for VBA code for automating this, and tried format painter from another workbook to the active one, but this does not seem to import the spaces.

Basically, I am looking for any way to automate this process, as at present, I am doing "Ctrl F: 1952", insert row, then rinse and repeat for each year.
I have to do this across 10 different sheets, so any assistance is gratefully accepted.

Comment: **In which cell is the date stored??**

Comment: In addition to @Gary'sStudent question, are all the sheets in your workbook needing this or just some?

Comment: It is one sheet, and the date is stored across 3 columns, so basically, I need it to be when Column A changes from 1951 to 1952, insert row, then repeat for 1953, 1954 etc up to 2011.

Comment: when you say "date is stored across 3 columns"  It conflicts with the statement "I need it to be when Column A changes"

Comment: Apologies for the confusion there.  The date is stored across 3 columns, but I am only using 1 column for referencing when it needs to have a row inserted.  The date is in the format YYYY (column A),MM(Column B), DD (Column C), so the most relevant one for this purpose is column A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some sample code that should get you pretty far along. While it would definitely be faster to use the find function in your code, I find that a bit more painful to work with, so I've taken the easy route here. Please note the assumptions listed in the code. You could expand this to work on multiple worksheets with a loop.

```
Sub InsertRowBetweenYears()

'ASSUMPTIONS:
'1) Years are listed in a single column
'2) Data is sorted by year from oldest to newest (we are going to loop backwards from newest to oldest)
'3) Sample data contained 3 columns: ColA = Random Word, ColB = Random Number, ColC = Year
'4) Sample data included years from 1950 to 1969.
'5) I tested having a variable number of rows per year, as well as having some years missing from the data

Dim rYears, test_year As Range
Dim cur_year As Long

'Make efficient
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'Set the first & last year expected in your data
Const START_YEAR = 1950
Const END_YEAR = 1969

'Set the range where you should look for the years (in a single column)
Set rYears = Range("C1:C40")

cur_year = END_YEAR

'Loop backwards through the years column and insert a row whenever the year changes
For r = (rYears.Rows.Count + rYears.Row - 1) To rYears.Row Step -1
    Set test_year = rYears.Offset(r - 1, 0).Resize(1)
    If test_year <> cur_year Then
        Rows(test_year.Row + 1).Insert shift:=xlDown, copyOrigin:=xlxlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

        'Update "cur_year" to the next year
        cur_year = test_year
    End If
Next

'Reset settings
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

**Pic of Sample data:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you! That was perfect!

You have just saved my sanity!  I am working with 2 climate model outputs for an input to a 3rd model I am creating, and the inserted row is vital....I have 5 models I am running for 50 years historically, and 50 years future, so you can imagine my frustration!

Comment: @Rhiaden - glad to hear it! Please go ahead and mark this as answered by clicking the checkmark next to the answer that you want to accept.

Comment: Done,and thanks once again for saving my sanity in my thesis!

Comment: @Rhiaden - oh wow! Good luck! If you're trying to do aggregations & analysis with the data, then I'd suggest that you perhaps side-step the inserting of rows and look into PivotTables or PowerPivot (depending on the version of Excel that you're using). If you have questions, follow up on a separate thread.

Answer (score 1):

This does what you are asking, although you may need to tweak it to your needs.

It inserts a new row at the end of each year.

It does NOT copy data

It does account for skipping years.

```
Sub InsertRowAfterYear()

Dim lastRow As Long
Dim tempYear As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lRow As Long

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    lRow = 2
    lastRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).row

    Do While lRow <= lastRow
            tempYear = ws.Cells(lRow, "A").Value       'Search Year in Column A

            If ws.Cells(lRow + 1, "A") <> tempYear Then
                tempYear = ws.Cells(lRow + 1, 1)
                ws.Cells(lRow + 1, 1).EntireRow.Insert
                lRow = lRow + 1
                lastRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).row
            End If
        lRow = lRow + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

[image: BEFORE][image: AFTER]

Comment: Another great solution :)